# BT client for java - no peers found

Tags: java, bittorrent

I am running an example for BT java implementation from https://atomashpolskiy.github.io/bt/ that can be found here:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.atomashpolskiy</groupId>
   <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Project source code:

```
Config config = new Config() {
            @Override
            public int getNumOfHashingThreads() {
                return Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
            }

            @Override
            public int getAcceptorPort() {
                return 6991;
            }
        };

        Module dhtModule = new DHTModule(new DHTConfig() {
            @Override
            public Collection<InetPeerAddress> getBootstrapNodes() {
                return Collections.singleton(new InetPeerAddress(config.getAcceptorAddress().getHostAddress(), Seeder.PORT));
            }
        });

        Path targetDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Downloads");

        // create file system based backend for torrent data
        Storage storage = new FileSystemStorage(targetDirectory);

        BtClient client = Bt.client()
                .config(config)
                .storage(storage)
                .magnet("magnet:?xt=urn:btih:20268DA0BA1C7E62F3DAC269A4F579156C754841&dn=The.Boys.S02E02.Proper.Preparation.and.Planning.1080p.AMZN.WEBRip.DDP5.1.x264-NTb&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.trackerfix.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.me%3A2980%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.to%3A2920%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce")
                .autoLoadModules()
                .module(dhtModule)
                .stopWhenDownloaded()
                .build();
        System.err.println("Starting leecher...");
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        client.startAsync(state -> {
            System.err.println("Peers: " + state.getConnectedPeers().size() + "; Downloaded: " + (((double)state.getPiecesComplete()) / state.getPiecesTotal()) * 100 + "%");
        }, 1000).join();
        System.err.println("Done in " + Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0));
```

I am trying it with a magnet that has over 50 peers but when I run the example it finds no peers at all. I have installed JCE as advised on in issues of the repository. With no luck. Where could lie the problem?

Current output at startup:

```
2021-01-01 11:32:18,329 [INFO] bt.runtime.BtRuntimeBuilder Loading standard extension module bt.peerexchange.PeerExchangeModule
2021-01-01 11:32:18,331 [INFO] bt.runtime.BtRuntimeBuilder Loading standard extension module bt.peer.lan.LocalServiceDiscoveryModule
2021-01-01 11:32:18,332 [INFO] bt.runtime.BtRuntimeBuilder Overriding auto-loaded module bt.dht.DHTModule
2021-01-01 11:32:18,333 [INFO] bt.runtime.BtRuntimeBuilder Auto-loading module bt.tracker.http.HttpTrackerModule with default configuration
2021-01-01 11:32:19,108 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,111 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,112 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/deploy.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,112 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,113 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/javaws.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,113 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,113 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/jce.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,169 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,169 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/jfr.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,170 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,170 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,171 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,171 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,171 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,171 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,171 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,172 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/plugin.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,172 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,172 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/resources.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,174 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,174 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/rt.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,176 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,177 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,196 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,196 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,204 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: null
2021-01-01 11:32:19,204 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/home/misko/.m2/repository/com/github/atomashpolskiy/examples/1.9/examples-1.9.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,205 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: com.github.atomashpolskiy.examples
2021-01-01 11:32:19,205 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Processing manifest file: jar:file:/home/misko/.m2/repository/com/github/atomashpolskiy/bt-core/1.9/bt-core-1.9.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,206 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bundle-SymbolicName: com.github.atomashpolskiy.bt-core
2021-01-01 11:32:19,206 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Will read version from manifest file: jar:file:/home/misko/.m2/repository/com/github/atomashpolskiy/bt-core/1.9/bt-core-1.9.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2021-01-01 11:32:19,206 [DEBUG] bt.service.ClasspathApplicationService Bt version 1.9
2021-01-01 11:32:19,359 [INFO] bt.net.portmapping.impl.PortMappingInitializer Mapping application's acceptor port on startup.
Starting leecher...
2021-01-01 11:32:19,478 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Schedule periodic cleanup of PEX messages
2021-01-01 11:32:19,479 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Initialize DHT facilities
2021-01-01 11:32:19,483 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Initialize message receiver
2021-01-01 11:32:19,484 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Schedule periodic cleanup of stale peer connections
2021-01-01 11:32:19,484 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Initialize message dispatcher
2021-01-01 11:32:19,491 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Initialize incoming connection acceptors
2021-01-01 11:32:19,495 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: Schedule periodic peer lookup
2021-01-01 11:32:19,498 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService <INFO> Starting DHT on port 49001
2021-01-01 11:32:19,499 [DEBUG] bt.runtime.BtRuntime Running startup hook: bt.net.portmapping.impl.PortMappingInitializer$$Lambda$96/294111720@51acdf2e
2021-01-01 11:32:19,500 [INFO] bt.net.SocketChannelConnectionAcceptor Opening server channel for incoming connections @ /192.168.0.155:6991
2021-01-01 11:32:19,522 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService Filtering addresses to bind DHT server to.. Checking /0.0.0.0.. Could use: false
2021-01-01 11:32:19,522 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService Filtering addresses to bind DHT server to.. Checking /192.168.0.155.. Could use: true
2021-01-01 11:32:19,522 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService Filtering addresses to bind DHT server to.. Checking /127.0.0.1.. Could use: false
2021-01-01 11:32:19,522 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService <INFO> updating set of valid bind addresses
 old: []
 new: [/192.168.0.155]
2021-01-01 11:32:19,551 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService <INFO> selecting default route bind/192.168.0.155
2021-01-01 11:32:19,568 [DEBUG] bt.dht.MldhtService <INFO> Starting RPC Server /192.168.0.155 0323FF9CAFDD293365BDBF29C8BE691D8D5EB4C3
2021-01-01 11:32:19,603 [DEBUG] bt.processor.ChainProcessor Processing next stage: torrent ID (20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841), stage (bt.processor.torrent.CreateSessionStage)
2021-01-01 11:32:19,609 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiling messaging agent type: bt.peerexchange.PeerExchangePeerSourceFactory
2021-01-01 11:32:19,692 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.protocol.extended.ExtendedHandshake}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,693 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.peerexchange.PeerExchange}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,693 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled producer method: produce
2021-01-01 11:32:19,693 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled 3 consumer/producer methods
2021-01-01 11:32:19,712 [DEBUG] bt.processor.ChainProcessor Finished processing stage: torrent ID (20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841), stage (bt.processor.torrent.CreateSessionStage)
2021-01-01 11:32:19,712 [DEBUG] bt.processor.ChainProcessor Processing next stage: torrent ID (20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841), stage (bt.processor.magnet.FetchMetadataStage)
2021-01-01 11:32:19,714 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiling messaging agent type: bt.torrent.messaging.MetadataConsumer
2021-01-01 11:32:19,714 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.magnet.UtMetadata}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,714 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.protocol.extended.ExtendedHandshake}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,714 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled producer method: produce
2021-01-01 11:32:19,714 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled 3 consumer/producer methods
2021-01-01 11:32:19,715 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiling messaging agent type: bt.torrent.messaging.BitfieldCollectingConsumer
2021-01-01 11:32:19,715 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.protocol.Have}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,715 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled consumer method {consumedType=bt.protocol.Bitfield}: consume
2021-01-01 11:32:19,715 [DEBUG] bt.torrent.compiler.MessagingAgentCompiler Compiled 2 consumer/producer methods
Peers: 0; Downloaded: 0.0%
Peers: 0; Downloaded: 0.0%
Peers: 0; Downloaded: 0.0%
Peers: 0; Downloaded: 0.0%
Peers: 0; Downloaded: 0.0%
2021-01-01 11:32:24,514 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker Executing tracker UDP request of type QUERY: AnnounceRequest{id=-1508983094, torrentId=20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841, peerId=2d4274010900002da0872cd927746781f7284767, downloaded=0, left=0, uploaded=0, eventType=QUERY(0), listeningPort=6991, requestString=/announce}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,514 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker Executing tracker UDP request of type QUERY: AnnounceRequest{id=-1507828847, torrentId=20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841, peerId=2d4274010900002da0872cd927746781f7284767, downloaded=0, left=0, uploaded=0, eventType=QUERY(0), listeningPort=6991, requestString=/announce}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,517 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Creating UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,517 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Creating UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,518 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Connecting UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0, remoteAddress=tracker.zer0day.to/69.16.230.42:1337}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,518 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Connecting UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0, remoteAddress=tracker.leechers-paradise.org/31.131.4.62:6969}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,660 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker Executing tracker UDP request of type QUERY: AnnounceRequest{id=-1454733499, torrentId=20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841, peerId=2d4274010900002da0872cd927746781f7284767, downloaded=0, left=0, uploaded=0, eventType=QUERY(0), listeningPort=6991, requestString=/announce}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,661 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Creating UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,661 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Connecting UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0, remoteAddress=coppersurfer.tk/31.14.40.31:6969}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,664 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker Executing tracker UDP request of type QUERY: AnnounceRequest{id=-1456272495, torrentId=20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841, peerId=2d4274010900002da0872cd927746781f7284767, downloaded=0, left=0, uploaded=0, eventType=QUERY(0), listeningPort=6991, requestString=/announce}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,666 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Creating UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,666 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Connecting UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0, remoteAddress=9.rarbg.me/151.80.120.115:2980}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,669 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker Executing tracker UDP request of type QUERY: AnnounceRequest{id=-1457811490, torrentId=20268da0ba1c7e62f3dac269a4f579156c754841, peerId=2d4274010900002da0872cd927746781f7284767, downloaded=0, left=0, uploaded=0, eventType=QUERY(0), listeningPort=6991, requestString=/announce}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,669 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Creating UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,669 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker Connecting UDP socket {localAddress=/192.168.0.155:0, remoteAddress=9.rarbg.to/151.80.120.113:2920}
2021-01-01 11:32:24,940 [DEBUG] bt.tracker.http.HttpTracker Executing tracker HTTP request of type QUERY; request URL: http://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce?info_hash=%20%26%8D%A0%BA%1C~b%F3%DA%C2i%A4%F5y%15luHA&peer_id=-Bt%01%09%00%00-%A0%87%2C%D9%27tg%81%F7%28Gg&ip=192.168.0.155&port=6991&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=0&compact=1&numwant=50&supportcrypto=1
```

Later on errors (which I assume are a result of broken tracker link):

```
2021-01-01 11:32:44,500 [WARN] bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource Peer collection finished with exception in peer source: TrackerPeerSource {UdpTracker{trackerUrl=http://tracker.zer0day.to:1337/announce}}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: bt.BtException: Failed to get peers for torrent
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource.schedulePeerCollection(ScheduledPeerSource.java:72) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource.update(ScheduledPeerSource.java:60) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.queryPeerSource(PeerRegistry.java:188) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.queryTracker(PeerRegistry.java:166) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.lambda$queryTrackers$5(PeerRegistry.java:154) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.queryTrackers(PeerRegistry.java:152) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.lambda$collectAndVisitPeers$3(PeerRegistry.java:132) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4649) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1082) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at bt.peer.PeerRegistry.collectAndVisitPeers(PeerRegistry.java:105) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_271]
Caused by: bt.BtException: Failed to get peers for torrent
    at bt.peer.TrackerPeerSource.collectPeers(TrackerPeerSource.java:62) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource.lambda$schedulePeerCollection$0(ScheduledPeerSource.java:81) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: bt.BtException: Failed to receive response from the tracker
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:101) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:103) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.createSession(UdpMessageWorker.java:88) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.getSession(UdpMessageWorker.java:82) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:77) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker$1.announceEvent(UdpTracker.java:142) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker$1.query(UdpTracker.java:122) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.TrackerPeerSource.collectPeers(TrackerPeerSource.java:54) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource.lambda$schedulePeerCollection$0(ScheduledPeerSource.java:81) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:96) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:103) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.createSession(UdpMessageWorker.java:88) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.getSession(UdpMessageWorker.java:82) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpMessageWorker.sendMessage(UdpMessageWorker.java:77) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker$1.announceEvent(UdpTracker.java:142) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.tracker.udp.UdpTracker$1.query(UdpTracker.java:122) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.TrackerPeerSource.collectPeers(TrackerPeerSource.java:54) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at bt.peer.ScheduledPeerSource.lambda$schedulePeerCollection$0(ScheduledPeerSource.java:81) ~[bt-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say it's an error, just a warning. Given multiple peer sources (trackers + DHT) the client should keep working even if one of the sources isn't operational. You either need a simpler test-case or you'll have to dig deeper and figure out the status of each peer source.

Based on the log timestamps you only waited a few seconds. If the peer sources were actually working and provided some IP addresses it's also possible that the client simply needs more time to try all of them to find a reachable contact.

You can also try wireshark to follow what's happening on the network level.

Comment: I let it run all day, after few hours it found only one peer. But no data were downloaded. I wanted to add trackers from the ubuntus transmision program but I have no idea how trackers are added with this library and I cannot find any example. I will try the wireshark though.